apart from membership in the set "diurnal, crepuscular, nocturnal', is "crepuscular" used only for what Fowler calls polysyllabic humor?
Outside of delimiting what part of the day different animals are active, What function does "crepuscular" serve that "twilight' doesn't? Is it like "terminological inexactitude" for a lie?

Well, Monk wrote "Crepuscule with Nellie", so there's at least one use

For poetic / expressive effect, which you seem to write off. Many words have synonyms that carry different loads.

Quite the contrary.  i found out about this monumentally ugly synonym or near-synonym of "twilight" only today and i felt almost physically hurt. @weathervane

You might find it ugly, but I do not. AFAIK it comes from the French crépusculaire.

yeah right - like "crepuscule of the gods" @weathervane

"crepuscular" is an adjective. What's the adjective form of "twilight"?

it is "twilit" - the debate is now off to the weeds - "the tomato is not a vegetable" kind of weeds. @barmar

Deer, for example, are crepuscular because they feel some safety in the dim light of both dusk and dawn, not just twilight, to leave forest and graze on delicate, sunny field greens.

@sk I speak Spanish, and "Crepúsculo" is the proper word that we use for twilight (and for the pre-sunrise half-light). Perhaps it is because of this that "crepuscular" sounds perfectly natural to me (although English is my first language), and indeed quite beautiful. Give a try at becoming accustomed to it before calling it monumentally ugly.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/sentences/crepuscular

Maybe it's because I'm not exactly a "morning person", but personally, I've always tended to associate twilight with the half-light of dusk far more than dawn. I still find it a bit surprising that the morning twilight occurs in print at levels comparable to the evening twilight.

'Crepuscular' is a more formal adjective used technically for things that occur around twilight. It is used primarily in biology for animals that are more active in the couple hours around sunrise and those around sunset (but not necessarily both) and inactive or sleeping during the full day -and- the full night. 'Diurnal' is for activities while the sun is up, and 'nocturnal' for when the sun has set. Since 'twilight' is primarily a noun, like dusk and dawn, the adjective 'crepuscular' is useful.
It is sometimes used metaphorically or poetically for the word 'twilight', though certainly not quite as much as 'twilight'. Any such replacement of a word in one register for another can be for humoristic ends, but the world is large and sometimes the big fancy word is really just a technically accurate one.
As to the relationship of 'terminological inexactitude' with 'lie', that connection is a rather terminological inexactitude, since a lie is an intentional falsehood, and a terminological inexactitude, as first used by Churchill, is a... well... inexactitude in terminology, or intentional vagueness to euphemize. And common usage has transformed 'termnological inexactitude' into a euphemism for lie.
As to the parallel (or lack thereof) of this relationship to the relationship of 'crepuscular' to 'having to do with twilight', there is no euphemizing or change in denotative meaning, they are straightforward synonyms in different registers.

@SK I'm not sure what you mean about 'time spent'. Was it too long? We try to give objective answers here even if the question is tendentious, and sometimes being objective requires more words to capture the nuance to avoid being opiniontated.

As to downvoting (and using the term 'kindergarten'), your question has a lot of assumed opinions and emotion in it. I suspect that's where downvoting might be elicited. You're looking for nuances that don't appear in any dictionary (which is what ELU is great for), and you're implicitly giving your motivation (you just saw this word and it feels overwrought to you) and the TLDR is that it's not overwrought, though presumably one could use any such latinate word in purple prose to get that effect.

Twilight/twilit has a couple of meanings where crepuscular isn't usually used: for instance a sense that something is coming to an end (Twilight of the Gods, etc), and dimly lit without the colours and soft tones of dawn or dusk. I think both can mean sinister, but talk of a "twilight world" has become a cliche

Sunbeam rays which emerge from clouds in a fan-shaped pattern as if radially oriented to the sun are called crepuscular (and anti-crepuscular) rays.
In actuality, the rays are paralell to each other, and only appear in a radial fashion to the human eye.
